# Homebrew is not upgrading all packages

Tags: mojave, install, homebrew, package-management, auto-update

Installed hashcat with brew `brew install hashcat` it says 6.1.1 version is installed and it's the latest when v6.2.3 stable is already up. How to fix it?

Comment: You may want to ask the Homebrew developers directly at their feedback/discussion page: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6.1.1 seems to be the version currently available via Homebrew (see https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/hashcat). If you need a newer version, consider creating a pull request for the formula or compile it directly from https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat.